# Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core (async)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I followed the code examples on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-a-handler-for-one-requirement

This all appears to work, but in order to use async/await calls I had to make some changes to the example provided by Microsoft and as this is security related I a little unsure and would appreciate some clarification.

Basically the changes I made were

1. Changed "Task" to "async TASK" on function defination
2. Changed "return Task.CompletedTask" to just "return;" (1st instance)
3. Remove the 2nd  "return Task.CompletedTask" at the end of the function as as dont think its needed

```
      protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SystemRoleRequirement2 requirement)
        {
            if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)) { return; } // Task.CompletedTask;
            var Result = (await _idb.QueryAsync<int>(cSQL.Security.SystemRoleAccess2, "SecurityReadOnly", new { UserID = context.User.ReadID(), requirement.SystemRoleIDs }))
                .SingleOrDefault();



           if (Result > 0) context.Succeed(requirement);
            //return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Can anyone confirm that this is the correct way to implement the security handler with await calls.

Comment: Those changes are all safe.

Comment: This question actually seems to be "how to I add 'async' to a method that returns a Task?" There's nothing special about the Authorization code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a method

```
private Task Foo(string input)
{
    if (input is null)
    {
        return Task.Complete;
    }

    input += " is processed";
    return Task.Complete;
}
```

The equivalent with `async` would be

```
private async Task Foo(string input)
{
    if (input is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    input += " is processed";
    return; // not needed as it's the last statement
}
```

So yes, your modifications are correct.